# The term 'go' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

After running...

```
go run main.go
```

I get this error

```
go : The term 'go' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify
that the path is correct and try again.
```

Comment: If you solved your own problem, put the solution in an answer, not in the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

SOLVED: Go to visual studio code (assuming this is installed) ctrl + shift + p to open command window type

> Go: current GOPATH

this should give you a path create a system environment variable named GOPATH and add that path into that variable.

Make sure the system environment variables are set to:

GOPATH is set (in my case) to C:\Users[username]\go

GOROOT is set to C:\go\

IDE is Visual Studio Code.

Comment: On Windows instillation, the Go MSI installs GOPATH as a user variable instead of a system variable. Thanks for the fix.

Comment: I get - Go: : The term 'Go:' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Comment: Restart VSCode is required.

Answer (score 11):

```
$env:Path = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("Path","Machine")
```

write the code to the terminal and run it. Eazy way to solve the problem.

Comment: this only works once and not permanently!

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue. Then found the below solution on the book "Learning Go" of O'REILLY.

If you are on a Unix-like system using bash, add the following lines to your .profile.
(If you are using zsh, add these lines to .zshrc instead):

```
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
```

You’ll need to source $HOME/.profile to make these changes take effect in your cur‐
rent terminal window.
On Windows, run the following commands at the command prompt:

```
setx GOPATH %USERPROFILE%\go
setx path "%path%;%USERPROFILE%\bin"
```

After running these commands, you must close your current command prompt and
open a new one for these changes to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of solutions:

- Run `refreshenv` to refresh the `PATH` environment variable in the current terminal session.

```
PS C:\> refreshenv
Refreshing environment variables from the registry for powershell.exe. Please wait...
Finished
PS C:\> go version
go version go1.18.4 windows/amd64
```

- Open a new terminal window and try again.
- Restart PC and try again.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue; I did a fresh installation of go programming language and official go extension in vscode. Then I restarted the vscode and the go command started working. Hope it helps!

Answer (score -2):

I was facing similar issues for commands installed via pip, I had to add the full path to `Scripts` folder to the PATH variable

```
C:\Users\username\.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.x.y\Scripts
```

For go too I believe something similar is to be done.